# using the buffer and transforming projection, PostGIS

Tags: sql, geospatial, postgis, wkt

I am creating a buffer and trying to transform my SRID to geog, then back to the original projection and geom.
My points layer has my WKT convention as such:

`POINT (-73.73891083685496 40.59593727361931)`

```
CREATE TABLE intrsct_buff AS ( 
  SELECT
    ST_Transform(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(pt.geom,2263), 60),4326) as geom, pt.count
  FROM public.intrsct_pts as pt
);
```

But when I use this code, my new buffer table has this WKT:

```
POLYGON ((-77.51963927750339 40.11249512168173..
```

Am I using the wrong SRID for the Geography? WGS84 = 4326. The projection it needs to be in is 2263, as that is the SRID of my points table and all other tables in my database.

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this, take a paper and a pen and write down what you need (input) and what you expect (output) for EVERY involved steps.

There is a mistake on almost every single assumption made.

1) `Geography` is not the same as `Geometry`. While both are using the WGS84 4326 CRS, the former unit is in meters while the second is in degrees. The former uses great circle arcs while the later uses straight lines to connects two points (distance computation, intersection etc are highly affected over large distances)

2) You say your data is in CRS [2263](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83-new-york-long-island-ftus/) (New York Long Island (ftUS)), which has the following bounds:

> WGS84 Bounds: -74.2700, 40.4700, -71.7500, 41.3100
>   Projected Bounds: 909126.0155, 110626.2880, 1610215.3590, 424498.0529

The coordinates you show are not in this CRS but more likely in WGS84.

Let's validate this assumption: if we (wrongly) assume that the coordinates you provided are in 2263, what happen if we project them to 4326?

```
select st_asText(st_transform(st_geomFromEWKT('SRID=2263;POINT (-73.73891083685496 40.59593727361931)'),4326));
                st_astext
------------------------------------------
 POINT(-77.5198536012811 40.112488506058)
```

Bingo, it is the result you are getting.
==> First, either fix the CRS you are using, or fix the coordinates. One of them IS wrong.

But even if you did had the proper CRS, the query would not work as intended.

You say you want to 1) change the point to geography, 2) buffer it by 60 meters, 3) convert back to the original CRS.

What you did was to 1) change the point to 2263 (it is already in the CRS, it has no effect) 2) buffer by 60 FEET 3) convert to WGS84 (geometry)

To achieve what you described, it would rather be:

```
SELECT ST_Transform(
     ST_Buffer(
      ST_Transform(pt.geom,4326)::geography, -- change to 4326 and cast to geography
      60), -- buffer 60 meters
    2263) as geom -- change back to original CRS
```

Comment: I tried this  solution but I am receiving an error on my first transform, saying  Error: function st_transform(geography, integer) does not exist. `CREATE TABLE intrsct_buff AS ( 
                    SELECT 
                    ST_Transform(
                    ST_Buffer(
                    ST_Transform(pt.geom,4326)::geography,
                    30.0),
                    2263) as geom, pt.count
                    FROM public.intrsct_pts as pt
                    );`     I assume this is saying I ned another argument in the first ST_Transform function(___, 2263)

Comment: no, it means you made another mistake in your assumptions (and it confirms the data is not in 2263). Trying formulas in a random order is a recipe for failure..., again, stop, look at what you have, what you want, and only then what has to be done to get it

Comment: Also remember that nested functions works from the inside to the outside. The transform to 2263 is the LAST one being applied.

Comment: I used the command `SELECT st_asText....` on my points table with SRID 2263 and "POINT(-73.738910836855 40.5959372736193)", which are correct points when I plot. So my original data is in 2263.

Comment: I understand the nested function, the code is  1)transforming projection of point data to new geography SRID  2) Buffering the geography SRID points by 30 m in each direction  3) re-projecting back to 2263 . Do I need to call the geography prior to the SRID 2263?

Comment: This coordinate in 2263 would be `POINT(1056757.91381836 156500.482604925)`